# Case query with groupings on generated column

Tags: database, postgresql, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is an example of some pseudo SQL I'm working on.

```
select count(*) as "count", time2.iso_timestamp - time1.iso_timestamp 
as "time_to_active",
case
when ("time_to_active" >= 1day and "time_to_active" <= 5days) then '1'
when ("time_to_active" >= 6days and "time_to_active" <= 11days) then 
'2'
when ("time_to_active" >= 12days and "time_to_active" <= 20days) then 
'3'
when ("time_to_active" >= 21days and "time_to_active" <= 30days) then 
'4'
when ("time_to_active" >= 31days) then '5'
end as timetoactivegroup
from t
inner join t1 on t.p_id = t1.p_id
join timestamp time1 on t.timestamp_id = t1.id
join timestamp time2 on t1.timestamp_id = t2.id
```

I'm essentially trying to query into groups where a calculated column fits into a range. Orders between *n* and *y* days kind of thing. The issue I'm running into mostly is generating the count based on groupings.

I can get the select query to display the calculated value without an issue.

Comment: I am not quiet sure what you are trying to do. Can you please specify your problem with sample data and expected output? You are trying to group some durations into different groups and then you want to count how many elements each of this group contains? Once I had a similar problem. I put the groups as range types into one table and joined against it with `JOIN ON a.range @> b.element` and resulted `a.id as group_id`. Second step: `group by group_id`

Answer (score 1):

postgresql doesn't let you group by an alias, so you'll need to repeat the grouping expression in the group by clause.

```
GROUP BY case
when ("time_to_active" >= 1day and "time_to_active" <= 5days) then '1'
when ("time_to_active" >= 6days and "time_to_active" <= 11days) then 
'2'
when ("time_to_active" >= 12days and "time_to_active" <= 20days) then 
'3'
when ("time_to_active" >= 21days and "time_to_active" <= 30days) then 
'4'
when ("time_to_active" >= 31days) then '5'
end
```

or you can group by the column number:

```
 GROUP BY 3
```

Comment: In snowflake database you can group by a column alias. But it is confusing as two databases are named.

Comment: why is the question tagged postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the pseudo SQL (time code), and also ignoring the table joins, where you are referring to an unnamed table `T2`

So if you have some rows with two timestamps `timestamp_a` which is earlier in time than `timestamp_b` then the error I see you might be having is the by doing the difference as a selected column `time2.iso_timestamp - time1.iso_timestamp as "time_to_active",` you have two columns that you need to group by, but you don't actually want the `time_to_active` in your answer, otherwise the case block aggregating the answers doesn't make much sense.

Thus in snowflake if I have a table with a few rows (this just representing how your joined tables would look..)

```
create or replace table t (timestamp_a timestamp_ntz, timestamp_b timestamp);

insert into t values ('2018-11-10','2018-11-11')
   ,('2018-11-08','2018-11-11')
   ,('2018-10-08','2018-11-11');

select datediff('day', timestamp_a, timestamp_b) as time_to_active from t;
```

gives `1,3,34` thus wrapping those into a sub-select (which could also be expressed as a CTE)

```
select case when (time_to_active >= 1 and time_to_active < 6) then '1'
          when (time_to_active >= 6 and time_to_active < 12) then '2'
          when (time_to_active >= 12 and time_to_active < 21) then '3'
          when (time_to_active >= 21 and time_to_active < 31) then '4'
          when (time_to_active >= 31) then '5'
    end as time_to_active_group
    ,count(*) as count 
from (
    select datediff('day', timestamp_a, timestamp_b) as time_to_active from t
) as A
group by time_to_active_group;
```

gives:

```
 1, 2
 5, 1
```

because we have 2 row between 1-5 and 1 in the >= 31 bucket.

another gotcha, is you have no handling for timestamps that are the "same day' or when the end time is before the start time, aka when `time_to_active <= 0`